# Beginner's attempt at TicTacToe

Tags: performance, algorithm, c, error-handling, tic-tac-toe

This is my attempt at making a basic TicTacToe game to play against another human player or a computer controlled opponent. The project was a lot harder for me than I initially thought it would be!

I have the feeling I've over complicated some things and think that especially the 'AI' part is not very elegant/efficient. For now tho this is the best I could do.

Would appreciate feedback on anything that comes to mind (program structure, optimization, bad practices etc.)

```
/*
 * tictactoe.c
 * 
 * Copyright 2024 Reslashd
 * 
 * A simple program to play Tic Tac Toe versus a friend or a
 * (very basic) computer controlled opponent.
 * 
 */

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

bool checkMove(char grid[][3], int move, bool move_ok);
int checkThree(char grid[][3], int three_row);
int checkTwo(char grid[][3], int move);
void clearScreen(void);
int cpuMove(char grid[][3], int move, int turn, int difficulty);
void drawGrid(char grid[][3]);
int gameLoop(char grid[][3], int choice, int difficulty, int three_row);
int getMove(char grid[][3], int move, char mark, int choice, int turns, int difficulty);
void makeMove(char grid[][3], int move, char mark);
bool needMove(bool need_move, int nX, int nO, int result);
int pickCpuMove(int move, int location);
void pressToContinue(void);
void resetGrid(char grid[][3]);
void resetVars(int *nX_ptr, int *nO_ptr, int *result_ptr);
int setDifficulty(int difficulty);
int showMenu(int choice);
void showScores(int n_owins, int n_xwins, int n_draws);
char startingMark(char mark, int choice);
char switchMark(char mark);

int main(void){
    char grid[3][3] = {{'1','2','3'}, {'4','5','6'}, {'7','8','9'}};
    int choice = 0;
    int difficulty = '1';
    int n_draws = 0;
    int n_owins = 0;
    int n_xwins = 0; 
    int three_row = 0; 
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    
    while ((choice = showMenu(choice)) != '5'){     
        if (choice == '1' || choice == '2'){
            three_row = gameLoop(grid, choice, difficulty, three_row);
            clearScreen();
            drawGrid(grid);
            if(three_row == 1){
                puts("\nThree in a row!");
                puts("O wins!");
                n_owins++;
            }
            else if (three_row == 2){
                puts("\nThree in a row!"); 
                puts("X wins!");
                n_xwins++;
            }   
            else{
                puts("\nIts a draw!");
                n_draws++;
            }   
            resetGrid(grid);
            three_row = 0;
            pressToContinue();
        } else if (choice == '3') { 
            showScores(n_owins, n_xwins, n_draws);
        } else if (choice == '4') {
            difficulty = setDifficulty(difficulty);     
        }       
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

bool checkMove(char grid[][3], int move, bool move_ok){
    size_t column = 0;
    size_t row = 0;
    
    if (move >= '1' && move <= '9'){            
        for (row = 0 ; row < 3; row++){
                for(column = 0; column < 3 ; column++){
                    if (grid[row][column] == move){ 
                        move_ok = 1;    
                        goto end_checkmove;                     
                    }   
                    else{
                        move_ok = 0;
                    }
                }               
        }       
    } else {
        move_ok = 0;
    }

    end_checkmove:
    return move_ok;
}

int checkThree(char grid[][3], int three_row){
    /*
     * This functions checks for 'three in a row' by checking the 
     * total decimal number in a row, column and diagonal.
     * 3 times decimal 79 (OOO) = 237
     * 3 times decimal 88 (XXX) = 264 
     * Returns 0 = draw, 1 = O wins, 2 = X wins
     */
     
    size_t column = 0;
    size_t row = 0;
    int result = 0; 

    // check diagonal left to right
    for (row = 0 ; row < 3; row++){
        result = result + grid[row][row];
        if (result == 237 || result == 264){
            if (result == 237) {
                three_row = 1;              
            } else{
                three_row = 2;
            }           
            goto return_result;
        }   
    }
    result = 0;
    
    // check diagonal right to left
    for (row = 0 ; row < 3; row++){
        result = result + grid[row][3 - row - 1];
        if (result == 237 || result == 264){
            if (result == 237) {
                three_row = 1;              
            } else{
                three_row = 2;
            }           
            goto return_result;
        }   
    }
    result = 0;

    // check rows
    for (row = 0 ; row < 3; row++){
        result = grid[row][0]+grid[row][1]+grid[row][2];    
        if (result == 237 || result == 264){
            if (result == 237) {
                three_row = 1;              
            } else{
                three_row = 2;
            }           
            goto return_result;
        }   
    }
    result = 0;
    
    // check columns
    for (column = 0 ; column < 3; column++){
        result = grid[0][column]+grid[1][column]+grid[2][column];   
        if (result == 237 || result == 264){
            if (result == 237) {
                three_row = 1;
            } else{
                three_row = 2;
            }
        }   
    }   

    return_result:  
    return three_row;
}

int checkTwo(char grid[][3], int move){
/*  
 *  This function checks if there are 2 XX's or OO's in a row,
 *  column or one of the diagonals and if a certain counter move by 
 *  the CPU is needed.  
 * 
 *  If needed it picks (randomly until the empty spot is found) a  
 *  counter move from a set of possible moves to either prevent a loss   
 *  or make a move to win the game.
 *  
 */
    size_t column = 0;
    size_t row = 0;
    
    bool need_move = 0;
    int nO = 0;
    int nX = 0;
    int result = 0;
        
    int *nX_ptr = &nX;
    int *nO_ptr = &nO;
    int *result_ptr = &result;  

    // check diagonal left to right 
    for (row = 0 ; row < 3; row++){
        result = result + grid[row][row];
        if(grid[row][row] == 'X'){
            nX++;
        }
        else if (grid[row][row] == 'O'){
            nO++;
        }   
    }   
    need_move = needMove(need_move, nX, nO, result);
    if (need_move == 1){
        move = pickCpuMove(move, 1);        
        goto return_move;
    }   

    resetVars(nX_ptr, nO_ptr, result_ptr);
        
    // check diagonal right to left 
    for (row = 0 ; row < 3; row++){
        result = result + grid[row][3 - row - 1]; 
        if(grid[row][3 - row - 1] == 'X'){
            nX++;
        }
        else if (grid[row][3 - row - 1] == 'O'){
            nO++;
        }
    }
    need_move = needMove(need_move, nX, nO, result);
    if (need_move == 1){
        move = pickCpuMove(move, 2);        
        goto return_move;
    }        

    resetVars(nX_ptr, nO_ptr, result_ptr); 

    // check rows 
    for (row = 0 ; row < 3; row++){ 
        resetVars(nX_ptr, nO_ptr, result_ptr);
        for(column = 0 ; column < 3; column++){
            if(grid[row][column] == 'X'){
                nX++;
            }
            else if(grid[row][column] == 'O'){
                nO++;               
            }
            result = grid[row][0]+grid[row][1]+grid[row][2];    
            need_move = needMove(need_move, nX, nO, result);
            if (need_move == 1){
                move = pickCpuMove(move, (int)row + 3); // location 3, 4, 5
                goto return_move;
            }   
        }   
    }   

    resetVars(nX_ptr, nO_ptr, result_ptr);
    
    // check columns 
    for (column = 0 ; column < 3; column++){    
        resetVars(nX_ptr, nO_ptr, result_ptr);
        for(row = 0 ; row < 3; row++){
            if(grid[row][column] == 'X'){
                nX++;
            }
            else if(grid[row][column] == 'O'){
                nO++;               
            }
            result = grid[0][column]+grid[1][column]+grid[2][column];   
            need_move = needMove(need_move, nX, nO, result);
            if (need_move == 1){
                move = pickCpuMove(move, (int)column + 6); // location 6, 7, 8
                goto return_move;
            }   
        }   
    }       

    move = (rand() % 9) + 49; // Failsafe return random move.
    return_move:    
    return move;    
}

void clearScreen(void){
    #if defined(__linux__) || defined(__unix__) || defined(__APPLE__)
        system("clear");
    #endif

    #if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
        system("cls");
    #endif
}

int cpuMove(char grid[][3], int move, int turn, int difficulty){
    char first_turn[5] = {'1','3', '5', '7', '9'};
    char second_turn[4] = {'1','3', '7', '9'};
    int n = 0;  
    
    if(turn == 1){
        // First turn strategy - take center or a corner
            n = rand() % 5;
            move = first_turn[n];   
    } else if (turn == 2){
        // Second turn strategy - take center if possible else a corner
        if(grid[1][1] != 'X' && grid[1][1] != 'O'){
            move = '5';
        }
        else if(grid[1][1] == 'X' || grid[1][1] == 'O'){
            n = rand() % 4;
            move = second_turn[n];
        }   
    } else if (turn == 3){
        // Third turn strategy - take center if possible else random move
        if(grid[1][1] != 'X' && grid[1][1] != 'O'){
            move = '5';
        }
        else {
            move = (rand() % 9) + 49; 
        }
        // Remaining turns
    } else {    
        //easy 
        if (difficulty == '1'){
            move = (rand() % 9) + 49;  // Random move '1' - '9'
        }
        // hard
        else if (difficulty == '2'){
            move = checkTwo(grid, move); // Analyze grid and make move
        }           
    }   
    return move;
}

void drawGrid(char grid[][3]){
    printf("\n%c | %c | %c\n", grid[0][0], grid[0][1], grid[0][2]);
    puts("=========");
    printf("%c | %c | %c\n", grid[1][0], grid[1][1], grid[1][2]);
    puts("=========");
    printf("%c | %c | %c\n", grid[2][0], grid[2][1], grid[2][2]);   
}

int gameLoop(char grid[][3], int choice, int difficulty, int three_row){
    int move = 0;
    int turn = 1;
    char mark = 'X';
    
    mark = startingMark(mark, choice);
    clearScreen();  
    while(turn != 10) {
        clearScreen();
        drawGrid(grid);
        move = getMove(grid, move, mark, choice, turn, difficulty);
        makeMove(grid, move, mark); 
        mark = switchMark(mark);
        turn++;
        three_row = checkThree(grid, three_row);
        if(three_row == 1 || three_row == 2){
            break;
        }       
    }
    return three_row;
}

void makeMove(char grid[][3], int move, char mark){ 
    size_t column = 0;
    size_t row = 0;
    
    for (row = 0 ; row < 3; row++){
        for(column = 0; column < 3 ; column++){
            if (grid[row][column] == move){ 
                grid[row][column] = mark;                       
            }   
        }               
    }
}

bool needMove(bool need_move, int nX, int nO, int result){
    if (nX == 2 || nO == 2){
        if (result < 237){
            need_move = 1;
        }        
    } 
    else{
        need_move = 0;
    }
    return need_move;
}

int pickCpuMove(int move, int location){
/*  
 *  Return a (random until empty spot is found) move from a 
 *  selection of moves based on where the sequence XX or OO was 
 *  found on the grid.
*/
    int n = 0;
    char diag_LR[3] = {'1', '5', '9'}; // location 1 
    char diag_RL[3] = {'3', '5', '7'}; // location 2
    char row_One[3] = {'1', '2', '3'}; // location 3
    char row_Two[3] = {'4', '5', '6'}; // location 4
    char row_Three[3] = {'7', '8', '9'}; // location 5
    char col_One[3] = {'1', '4', '7'}; // location 6
    char col_Two[3] = {'2', '5', '8'}; // location 7
    char col_Three[3] = {'3', '6', '9'}; // location 8
    n = rand() % 3;
    
    if(location == 1){
        move = diag_LR[n];
    } else if(location == 2){
        move = diag_RL[n];
    } else if(location == 3){
        move = row_One[n];
    } else if (location == 4){
        move = row_Two[n];
    } else if (location == 5){
        move = row_Three[n];
    } else if(location == 6){
        move = col_One[n];
    } else if (location == 7){
        move = col_Two[n];
    } else if (location == 8){
        move = col_Three[n];
    }
    return move;
}

void pressToContinue(void){
    puts("\nPress ENTER to continue");
    getchar();
    getchar();  
}

void resetGrid(char grid[][3]){
    size_t column = 0;
    size_t row = 0; 
    char first = '1';
    
    for (row = 0 ; row < 3; row++){
        for(column = 0; column < 3 ; column++){
            grid[row][column] = first;
            first++;        
        }               
    }   
    
}
void resetVars(int *nX_ptr, int *nO_ptr, int *result_ptr){
    *nX_ptr = 0;
    *nO_ptr = 0;
    *result_ptr = 0;    
}

int setDifficulty(int difficulty){
    int input = 0;
    clearScreen();
    puts("\n***** SET DIFFICULTY *****\n");
    if (difficulty == '1'){
        puts("Current difficulty is EASY\n");
    } else if (difficulty == '2'){
        puts("Current difficulty is HARD\n");
    }
    puts("1 = Easy");
    puts("2 = Hard");
    fputs("\nChoose your difficulty: ", stdout);
    getchar();
    input = getchar();
    
    if (input == '1'){              
        difficulty = '1';               
        puts("Difficulty set to EASY");
    } else if (input == '2'){
        difficulty = '2';   
        puts("Difficulty set to HARD");
    }
    else{
        puts("\nInvalid choice!");
    }   
    pressToContinue();  
    return difficulty;
}

int showMenu(int choice){
    clearScreen();
    puts("\nTIC TAC TOE v1.0 by Reslashd");
    puts("\n******* MENU *******\n");
    puts("1 = 1 Player vs CPU");
    puts("2 = 2 Players");
    puts("3 = View scores");
    puts("4 = Set difficulty"); 
    puts("5 = Exit");
    choice = getchar();
    return choice;
}

void showScores(int n_owins, int n_xwins, int n_draws){
    clearScreen();
    puts("\n***** SCORES *****");
    printf("\nO has %d wins", n_owins);
    printf("\nX has %d wins", n_xwins); 
    printf("\nThere are %d draws\n", n_draws);
    pressToContinue();
}

char startingMark(char mark, int choice){
    int start_mark = 0;
        
    puts("\nPlease choose starting player");
    if (choice == '1'){
        puts("1 = O (CPU)");
    } else if (choice == '2'){
        puts("1 = O");
    }
    puts("2 = X");
    getchar();
    start_mark = getchar();
    if (start_mark == '1'){
        mark = 'O';
    } else if (start_mark == '2'){
        mark = 'X';
    }
    return mark;
}

char switchMark(char mark){
    if (mark == 'X'){
        mark = 'O';
    } else if (mark == 'O') {
        mark = 'X';
    }   
    return mark;
}

int getMove(char grid[][3], int move, char mark, int choice, int turn, int difficulty){ 
    bool move_ok = 0;
    
    // get Human player move 
    if(choice == '2' || (choice == '1' && mark == 'X')){    
        while(move_ok != 1){                
            printf("\nIt is %c's turn, place your mark: ", mark);
            while((move = getchar()) == '\n');  
        
            move_ok = checkMove(grid, move, move_ok);
            if (move_ok != 1){
                puts("Invalid move please try again...");
                pressToContinue();
                clearScreen();
                drawGrid(grid);
            } 
        }
    }
    // get CPU move
    else if (choice == '1' && mark == 'O'){     
        while (move_ok != 1){   
            move = cpuMove(grid, move, turn, difficulty);
            move_ok = checkMove(grid, move, move_ok);
        }                                       
    }
    return move;    
}
```

Comment: Why magic numbers 49, 79, 88?  If code needs the value of the character `'O'`, Why not use `'O'` instead of 79 or `'O' + 'O' + 'O'` instead of 237?

Comment: What happens if you Ctrl+D (or Ctrl+Z on Windows/DOS) while at the menu? For me, it was an endless loop because EOF is not handled.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, you know they have a shorthand notation for repeated addition, now, don't you? Not sure if the Stack sites have got the upgraded version of Unicode installed, but try `'O' \x00D7  3`...

Comment: @aghast Source coding outside the allowed subset of ASCII leads to its own troubles.  Let's go with `3* 'O'`.

Comment: @ chux - Reinstate Monica > no specific reason it was just the (maybe not optimal) solution I came up with.

Comment: @aghast > the program indeed runs in a endless loop here when I press Ctrl+D. I'm not sure why tho? Could you elaborate why this happens and what I can do to fix this?

Comment: @Reslashd When you are taking input from a stream, one possibility is that you will encounter "end of file". Depending on what function you call, it gets handled differently. It may just be the end of a string, or it may cause a return of `NULL` or a return of `EOF`. In cases where you are reading characters, `EOF` is returned. This is an integer value outside the range of a `char,` so you have to special-case it. If you ignore EOF and ask for another character of input, you get... EOF! It's like a horror movie villain, it just keeps coming back. You need to detect it and ... whatever.

Comment: @ aghast Thank you.  I think I've fixed it by doing an extra check as suggested: while ((choice = showMenu()) != '5' && choice != EOF). For other people that might stumble on this topic this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28216437/end-of-file-in-stdin) made it more clear for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing that comes to mind is to remove `goto` (see [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful)):

- `checkMove` you only need to check a single cell not up to 9 with loops

```c
bool checkMove(char grid[][3], int move) { // wouldn't pass move_ok
  bool move_ok;
  if (move >= '1' && move <= '9') {
    // convert from ascii to int, then to position
    int row = (move - 49) / 3;
    int column = (move - 49) % 3;
    if(grid[row][column] == move) {
      move_ok = 1;
    } else {
      move_ok = 0;
    }
  } else {
    move_ok = 0;
  }
  return move_ok;
}
```

- `makeMove` can be very similar to `checkMove` (don't need loop)

```c
// convert from ascii to int, then to position
int row = (move - 49) / 3;
int column = (move - 49) % 3;
grid[row][column] = mark
```

- `checkThree` you could easily check cell equality in a single line, and then `return` immediately instead of using `goto`. Also use bool

```c
bool checkThree(char grid[][3]) {//don't need three_row
// left to right diagonal
if (grid[0][0] == grid[1][1] && grid[1][1] == grid[2][2]) {
  return true;
}
...
return false; // you don't treat 1 or 2 differently from this function
```

this would require slightly different validating

```c
three_row = checkThree(grid);//don't need to pass three_row
if (three_row){
  if(mark == 'O') {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 2;
  }
}
...
```

- `checkTwo` could be very similar to `checkThree`, just expand the check (I think you can remove `needMove`, `pickCpuMove`, or `resetVars`)

```c
move = '0'
// left to right diagonal
if (grid[0][0] == grid[1][1] && grid[1][1] != grid[2][2]) {
  // know 2 are the same, but not the last
  return '9';
} else if (grid[0][0] != grid[1][1] && grid[1][1] == grid[2][2]) {
  // know last are the same, but not the first
  return '1';
} else if (grid[0][0] == grid[2][2]) {
  // know ends are the same, but not the mid
  return '5'
}
...
```

Simplify:

- `if (grid[1][1] != 'X' && grid[1][1] != 'O')` can be `if (grid[1][1] != '5')`
- `} else if (grid[1][1] != 'X' || grid[1][1] == 'O') {` can be `} else {`
- `} else if (mark == 'O') {` can be `} else {`
- don't need to pass so many arguments

  - `getMove` doesn't need `move`, it should return `move` (`cpuMove`, `pickCpuMove` (unless you remove it as noted above) also don't need it, same reason)
  - IMO using function parameters as variables is confusing. Generally I treat function parameters as read-only (there are exceptions to this (see [pass by reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pass-by-reference-in-c/)), but when I read `myVar = myFunc(myVar)` I don't expect `myVar` to change inside `myFunc`). In `setDifficulty` I would do something like:

```c
  if (input == '1') {
    puts("Difficulty set to EASY");
    return '1';
  } else if (input == '2') {
    puts("Difficulty set to HARD");
    return '2';
  } else {
    puts("\nInvalid choice! Difficulty will remain the same");
    return difficulty
  }
```

**EDIT**
Based on https://github.com/Reslashd/tictactoe/blob/main/tictactoe.c

Variable/parameter clean up

- clear names: Reading a variable should let future you/devs know what is stored in it.
- don't pass basic variables as parameters to edit

  - in `main`, `three_row` has several issues. It isn't very clear what it stores. I'd change it `winner` and remove it as a parameter to `gameLoop`. `gameLoop` without the parameter could just put the check in the `if`: `if(checkThree(grid))` and the final `return` would be `return 0` (no winner)
  - `switchMark` is assigning to `mark`, instead it should just `return`. Shorter and clearer code. Don't treat parameters as editable variables, generally should be read only
  - in `gameLoop` just initialize `mark` without passing `mark`: `char mark = startingMark(choice)` (might rename to `getStartingMark`). Inside `startingMark` change the parameter name to be something like `numPlayers` instead of `choice` (clear what is being passed in). The logic of `startingMark` isn't very clear. It initializes `start_mark` to an int later it's a char (technically stored same, but to be clear to developer distinguish the type better).
  - `showMenu` doesn't need `choice`, it returns the player choice, initialize choice like `char choice = getchar();`
- change parameter names to be different than what you pass. This might help separate use/difference

  - `setDifficulty` the parameter could be `currentDifficulty`. Side note, inside this function input could be initialized in on line with correct type `char input = getchar();`
  - `switchMark` the param could be `currentMark`

Simplify Again

- 99% of the time if you see a pattern it can be simplified

  - `checkTwo` and `checkThree` row/col check could be put in a `for` loop. `checkTwo`'s fail safe return should validate the random choice is a valid move like all the rest (as `cpuMove` also has a rand choice, you make a rand choice function, then you won't have to check it later):

```
  char randMove;
  do{
    randMove = (rand() % 9) + 49;   
  }while(!checkMove(grid, randMove));
  return randMove; // Failsafe return random move.
```

All these together: https://gist.github.com/depperm/b28798d3730c0f8394fd1ed380fa95e5 (almost 100 lines shorter)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. I will go over it in detail this weekend and see if I understand everything and if I can implement some improvements.
Will probably get back to you with some additional questions.

Question about the GOTO; I can understand in this case it is poor design (I think I can implement your better alternative solution). I am wondering tho: besides being a poor design choice could the way I've used them in this program (break out of a nested loop) also cause unforeseen problems or bugs I might not be aware of?

Comment: @Reslashd maybe, this is a fairly simple program, its more of good practice not to use

Comment: I had to make an addition to your suggested improvement for checkTwo or else the program gets stuck in an infinite loop. If for example the first row = "O X O" it would return '2' while there already is an X in that position on the grid and thats not possible. So to fix this I've added a checkMove before returning a move i.e. if(checkMove('9')) before returning '9'. I feel the function still is a bit bloated tho but you were right; I could get rid of the mentioned functions which is great! I wonder if there is a way to further optimize the checkTwo function?

Comment: The simplifying suggestions also make sense though these too had to be modified a bit i.e. if (grid[1][1] == '5') (take center position on the grid if no X or O there). Question about the returning of values by a function: If I understand correctly this immediately also ends the function? What is the advantage of returning a value directly instead of a variable (like in the setDifficulty function? [link](https://github.com/Reslashd/tictactoe/blob/main/tictactoe.c) to updated code.

Comment: @Reslashd advantage is run less logic: faster, less chance of edge case/error. IMO variables come in handy if you are performing multiple computations. I can add further edit in a few minutes

Comment: Thank you for your extensive feedback and all the suggested improvements! In the future I will definitely try to only pass variables to functions if they are actually needed and also try keep them 'read only' and give them clearer names. I do get some warnings now tho when compiling: tictactoe.c:28:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype  28 (and 390) | char showMenu(); --> should be showMenu(void)? or is this type of declaring allowed? The other is about conversions from char to int. I think you did this for clarity reasons (?) but shouldn't it be INT var_name = getchar(); ?

Comment: @Reslashd yes it should be declared with void. Its been a while since I've done C and forget the reason getchar should be int, is the EOF. I'll update the gist

Answer (score 3):

We can easily change the order of functions so we don't need to forward-declare so many (possibly none at all).  That's why C programmers expect to find `main()` *last* in the file.

---

It looks like you're assuming your code will run in an ASCII locale - the computations are completely broken where `'X'`, `'O'` and/or `' '` are encoded differently.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I understand I can avoid the forward declaring but other than style/preference is there a specific reason not to?

About the ASCII locale; I'll be honest I hadn't thought about that...

Comment: The main reason not to forward-declare is that it's extra effort you probably don't need.  It's clearly easier if any changes can be made in a single place, rather than needing two edits.

Comment: You are right that it is a bit of a pain to change it at two places in the code. As I've understood it tho it can help the compiler spot some subtle errors [link](https://stefansf.de/post/declaring-defining-and-prototyping-functions/). Since I'm a beginner I think it's a good idea for now to keep doing it this way. Or are there any other downsides that I've perhaps missed or not understood correctly?

Comment: Your link is to something different, mostly referencing the old style of declaring functions with _unspecified arguments_ (`()`).  Every function should have a _prototype_, but it's fine for the prototype to also be the _definition_.